# Iterate a php array conversion to json on add last table in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have an array that I converted into json. The result will be to interprated into select option in add last row.

The code looked like this :

```
 $(document).on('click', '#addRow', function() {
        var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($type); ?>;
        $.each(arrayFromPHP, function(i, elem) {
            console.log(elem);
        });

        $("#tableReport").find('tbody').append($('<tr>\n\
                <td><select>"<?php echo '<option> Value </option>' ?>"</select></td>\n\
                </tr>'));
    });
```

How can I pass the json into select option in `append` ?

**UPDATED**

Now, I have success to manipulate it if just one array. But, I have 4 php's array. It should be a function or I create array on array.
Now my code is looked like tjis :

```
function selOP (arrayJSON, value){
        var selStr ='<select>';

        $.each(arrayJSON, function(i, elem) {

            selStr += '<option>' + elem.value+ '</option>';

        });

        return selStr += '</select>';
    }


    $(document).on('click', '#addRow', function() {
        var type = <?php echo json_encode($type); ?>;
        var item = <?php echo json_encode($item); ?>;


        var selType = '<select>';
        var selItem = '<select>';


        $.each(type, function(i, elem) {
            selType += '<option>' + elem.NAMA_TYPE + '</option>';

        });

        $.each(item, function(i, elem) {
            selItem += '<option>' + elem.NAMA_ITEM + '</option>';

        });
        selType += '</select>';
        selItem += '/<select>';

        $("#tableReport").find('tbody').append('<tr><td>' + selType + '</td><td>'+ selItem +'</tr>');

    });
```

Any solution it so appreciated.

Comment: wrong tags. Issue is not with php.

Comment: no problem :) send you edit for that. I am more then happy to remove minus from post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the code as below :

```
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function() {
   var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($type); ?>;
   var selStr = '<select>';
   $.each(arrayFromPHP, function(i, elem) {
        selStr += '<option>' + elem.yourValue + '</option>';
   });
   selStr += '</select>';
   $("#tableReport").find('tbody').append('<tr>\n\<td>'+selStr+</td>\n\</tr>');

});
```

First create the string for the select using each then append the same to the table as new row

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

I would say simply put the append inside your $.each:

```
$(document).on('click', '#addRow', function() {
    var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($type); ?>;
    $.each(arrayFromPHP, function(i, elem) {
        $("#tableReport").find('tbody').append('<tr>\n\<td><select>"<option>' + elem.yourValue + '</option>'"</select></td>\n\</tr>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it will be iterate select too,